# How get from url params?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a links

```
http://example.com/abc/389834893284
```

I tried create .htaccess but still not working. When i go for that link i wanna have two params in index.php is any way to do that ?

```
[0] => 'abc'
[1] => '389834893284',
```

This is my htaccess but i have a Internal Server Error

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?params=$1 [NC, QSA]
```

Comment: Can you please show the `.htaccess` code you have tried?

Comment: Or any attempts at researching this?

Comment: That's a path, so you have folders, not parameters. Also this is unrelated to PHP specifically.

Comment: works fine now. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\d+)/& /index.php?word=$1&number=$2 [END]
```

That way you can access the two values as `$_GET['word']` and `$_GET['number']` or by whatever name you use for those arguments.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).